# how to enable comparison between Vec<_> and Vec<_,CustomAllocator>?

Tags: rust, memory-management

I am trying to use a custom allocator, using the [allocator API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/library-features/allocator-api.html) in Rust.

It seems Rust considers `Vec<u8,CustomAllocator>` and `Vec<u8>` as two distinct types.

```rust
    let a: Vec<u8,CustomAllocator> = Vec::new_in(CustomAllocator);
    for x in [1,2,3] { a.push(x) }

    let b:Vec<u8> = vec![1,2,3];
    assert_eq!(a,b);
```

It means that a simple comparison like the below won't compile:

```
error[E0277]: can't compare `Vec<u8, CustomAllocator>` with `Vec<u8>`
  --> src/main.rs:37:5
   |
37 |     assert_eq!(a,b);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no implementation for `Vec<u8, CustomAllocator> == Vec<u8>`
   |
   = help: the trait `PartialEq<Vec<u8>>` is not implemented for `Vec<u8, CustomAllocator>`
   = note: this error originates in the macro `assert_eq` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I can't implement the trait, as I don't own either `Vec` or `PartialEq`.

In reality, and in the context of my implementation, I *may* compare both underlying slices. But I don't see how I can achieve this with the language...

Any clue appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried comparing slices instead? `assert_eq!(&a[..], &b[..])`

Comment: @PitaJ that seems to work indeed!

Comment: @PitaJ This can be shortened to `assert_eq!(a[..], b[..])`.

Comment: Opened a PR: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/93755

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**
Since GitHub pull request [#93755](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/93755) has been merged, comparison between `Vec`s with different allocators is now possible.

---

**Original answer:**

`Vec` uses the [`std::alloc::Global`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/alloc/struct.Global.html) allocator by default, so `Vec<u8>` is in fact `Vec<u8, Global>`. Since `Vec<u8, CustomAllocator>` and `Vec<u8, Global>` are indeed distinct types, they cannot directly be compared because the `PartialEq` implementation is not generic for the allocator type. As @PitaJ commented, you can compare the slices instead using `assert_eq!(&a[..], &b[..])` ([which is also what the author of the allocator API recommends](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/jymzdw/the_story_continues_vec_now_supports_custom/gd7dtw4/?context=3)).